# Depending on the page, show different content in WordPress (like is_home, but for other pages)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

First I should explain my site structure. I have WordPress pages (with each their own `page-{id}.php` template to change what they look like), these are also the main pages on my website. Consider these an overview, so like a catalogue in a store (which my website is not, but it's a good comparison)

On these pages I show a list of links (to continue the metaphor, the products of that store) to other pages, when I click on one of these links I go to a new page with actual content (a detailed view of the product in our metaphor). These pages are WordPress posts and are influenced by the `single_post.php` template.

Now the problem, for four out of five pages there is no problem and the `single_post.php` template does a great job. But for the last page I wanted to go a different route, but I cannot change the contents of that page because if I do, I'd have to change the `single_post.php` template file and break the other pages.

So here's my question, I'm aware of the `is_home` function in WordPress and I was wondering if there is a way to check in the `single_post.php` file which page I'm on and depending on if I'm on one of the four good pages or the one bad page, I show different content? (Basically is there something like the `is_home` function where you change the "home" part to a specific name of a page?)

This doesn't have to be something specific like the `is_home`, a regular javascript or something would work just fine too.

Comment: `if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'myfile.php')` or same approach with `in_array`.

Comment: I'll probably try that as well, but if I could get the 'if is single' below working, that would be even better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use is_single function like below to check you are in which post:

```
if(is_single(123)) // Here check if post id equal 123
    // some code

if(is_single("My post") // Here check if post title equal My post
    // some code

if(is_single("my-post-slug") // Here check if post slug equal my-post-slug
    // some code
```

Comment: That does seem like what I'm looking for so I'm gonna accept that as the aswer, it didn't really help me though. I put the "if is single" and an "else" before line 10 in my code here, but it kind of broke...

https://pastebin.com/HeM8D2XN